# import common python file in codeUri in template.yaml for sam applications

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

I  have  the follwing folder structure

```
src
-- foo
  --lambda1.py
-- blah
   --lambda2.py
-- util
    --util.py
```

Now i would to create to include util.py in both the lambda functions code uri  using the template.yaml.So that i dont have to maintain two copies of same util.py in lambda1 folder and lambda2 folder.

Here is the template.yaml i am using  :

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion : '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
  SAMDEMOLAMBDA1:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: samdemoLambda1.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python2.7
      CodeUri: ./src/foo
      Events:
                HelloWorld:
                    Type: Api 
                    Properties:
                        Path: /hello
                        Method: get

  SAMDEMOLAMBDA2:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: samdemoLambda2.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python2.7
      CodeUri: ./src/blah
      CodeUri: ./src/util
```

How could i  import this common util.py in lambda 2

Comment: I solved it  by making util.py as a python module and then  pushed this module to reposiroty from where it can be downaloaed as a  depedency from requirements.txt.But please do let me know if this can be handled from codeURi as well.

Comment: were you able to achieve this without uploading it to repository?

Comment: no i could not .

Comment: You can use [layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html)

Comment: is your requirements.txt just in `src`? When i try this, only my files relative to CodeUri (./src/blah/) get deployed to the lambda, so it is not able to import anything from requirements.txt